# Removing IIS server header from WebDeploy on port 8172

Tags: security, owasp, iis-10, pci-dss, hardening

I'm looking after a bit of server hardening for PCI DSS and can remove the headers from IIS no problem for standard sites but my compliance scanner is reporting (correctly) that port 8172 for MS Web deployment of packages is announcing the IIS/10 server header and that's a PCI compliance fail.

I've tried manually adding a URL Rewrite rule in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administrator.config but that hasn't worked.

There don't appear to be any settings for controlling the WMSvc, Management Service whatever you want to call it.

Just asking in case anyone else has found the magic setting.

I know I could disable webdeploy between uses, firewall it or even not use it but I'm sure there must be an answer given how trivial it is!

Thanks

Comment: This link should help you: [Remove Unwanted HTTP Response Headers](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710).

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately I've been through all of those with only one left to try which was the clear in applicationHost.config but nothing working.

It all works just fine on actual IIS sites but not on the Web Management Service used for MS Deploy

Comment: Are you using URL Rewrite? As far as I know, if you use url rewrite to remove the server header, the url rewrite rule should be in web.config not applicationHost.config.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm using URL Rewrite for all of the actual sites on the server and that rule is in the main web.config at server level and that all works.

What doesn't seem to work is when a scanning tool hits https://www.server.com:8172 which generates a 404 with the following output from curl:

`HTTP/2 404 
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
date: Thu, 15 Sep 2022 11:48:15 GMT
content-length: 0`

Done the settings for HTTP.sys and used all of the removeServerHeader attributes I can find.

Consistently the 404 on port 8172 reports that it's Microsoft-IIS/10.0 though and it's killing me!

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.